# Initializing form control with the array from server not working

Tags: angular, reactjs

My requirement is to iterate over the data coming from server and create a formGroup of checkboxes.My sample html code is

```
 <div *ngFor="let rel of formGroup.controls['releases'].controls;let i = index" style="display:inline-block">
   <clr-checkbox [formControl]="rel" 
          [clrInline]="true">
           {{releases[i].item_text}}
         </clr-checkbox>
</div>
```

In component ngOnInit I am fetching the data from server and assiging to formGroup.In ngOnInit i have defined formGroup as

```
this.formGroup=this.formBuilder.group({
  releases:this.formBuilder.array(this.releases)
})



this._releaseHandler.getVersionsFromBackend().subscribe((x:Array<any>)=>{     
  x.forEach((value,index)=>{
    this.releases.push({id:index,item_text:value.Release_Name})
  })
  this.buildFormGroup()
}),error=>{console.log(error),()=>{
console.log("Called")
}}
```

After fetching the data i am creating formGroup in **buildFormGroup**

```
  buildFormGroup(){   
 this.formGroup.controls['releases'].setValue(this.formBuilder.array(this.releases)
}
```

Data coming from service from **getVersionsFromBackend**

```
 getVersionsFromBackend(){
return this._http.get(this._backendUrl+"/getReleaseDetails").pipe(shareReplay(1))
 }
```

But everytime formControl is not getting any value.Its most probably because of data coming from server by that time its form already executed.

Comment: I would suggest if you don't have any important dependencies, to use Angular technique called Resolver:
Reference -> https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers/, https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-resolve/       ==>This technique is used to load data before the component is loaded

Comment: @Itamar Thanks for your suggestion.For now i resolved this by using this.formGroup.setControl('release',this.formBuilder.array(this.releases))

Comment: @Itamar I tried with resolver and it worked really great.Please post your answer i will accept that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest, in case you don't have any important dependencies, 
to use Angular technique called **Resolver**:

- **Reference**

  - https://alligator.io/angular/route-resolvers,
  - https://www.techiediaries.com/angular-router-resolve/
- This technique is used to load data before component is loaded, which is much more elegant and clear